# How to crash a Linux VM?

Tags: linux, bash, crash

I have created a monitoring system which restarts the VM when it becomes unresponsive or has crashed internally. I want to simulate the VM crashing, so I can test my monitoring setup. I tried the fork-bomb but it did not crash it. I also tried calling processes in an infinite loop.

Need a clean way of crashing the VM successfully, without any later consequences.

Comment: try this one on the linux terminal, i think it should work.... echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger       and tell me if it worked

Comment: Check: http://life-is-a-hack.blogspot.de/2009/08/6-ways-to-crash-your-linux-because-its.html

Comment: @AniMenon yeah definitely don't do them, some will destroy your VM not just crash it.

Comment: If the monitoring system uses TCP, you can just turn off the network in the VM. something like `service networking stop` or `ifconfig eth0 down`

Comment: @anishsane The monitoring is done by ping testing the VM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. This would cause a kernel panic.
   Linux :

   `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`

   More info [here](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt)

   On Linux, you might have to `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` before you are able to

   `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger`
2. I know you already used a fork bomb i just write it again for reference, or maybe you could also try that again:

   `:(){ :|:& };:`
3. Compile the following code into a module and insmod it, sure you should get a panic:

`

```
static int crash_module_init(void){
    printf("crash module starting\n");
    int *p = 0;
    printk("%d\n", *p);return 0;
}
static void crash_module_exit(void){
    printf("crash module exiting\n");
}
module_init(crash_module_init);
module_exit(crash_module_exit);
```

`

Comment: Would I be able to recover my machine after restart? I do not want to wreck it.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh yeap, this is just going to freeze the system, not destroy it... :)

Comment: I tried to do this it gives me permission denied even as the root user.

Comment: @LovepreetSingh did you do the `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` first?

Comment: That is what gave the permission denied

Comment: @LovepreetSingh did you try just the other one?

Comment: @LovepreetSingh i meant try this first `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger` and if that doesnt work then try the second one as well before the other...

Comment: I tried it both ways. Permission denied on both instances. I think I might have to change permissions first.

Answer (score 3):

First enable SysRq in your vm, and type the following and system will crash.

```
 echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Here's [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)! for details.

When the magic SysRq key combination is pressed with the command "c", it causes a kernel panic.

Answer (score 1):

As OP mentioned, he is using `ping $VM_IP` to test if the VM has crashed. So, if `ping` fails, it would be considered as VM crash. So, the least intrusive change to trigger failure recovery would be to disable the network.

```
service networking stop # Or maybe 
service network stop # or
ifconfig eth0 down # Or whatever your interface's name is... eth1/eno1 etc...
```

Comment: But I still wish to simulate a crashing/unresponsive VM that if it still answers pings or not when it is in the crash state i.e also want to test if ping test is infact the right way to go or not.